# Login is not working in custom User modal in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have created custom user model consist of username and password and I use logged in through the username and password but when i try to login the login is not working

**register_app/model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

# Create your models here.
class Register(models.Model):
   
    class Meta:
        db_table = "register"

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email=models.EmailField()

class HandleloginManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password=None):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("username is required")
        user = self.model(
            username = self.username,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class Handlelogin(AbstractBaseUser):

    class Meta:
        db_table = "login"

    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique = True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    register = models.OneToOneField(Register, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    USERNAME_FIELD="username"

    REQUIRES_FIELD=['password']

    objects = HandleloginManager()
```

**register_app/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, HttpResponse
from .models import Register, Handlelogin
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
        return render(request, 'home.html')

def register(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.POST.get('firstname') and request.POST.get('lastname') and request.POST.get('username')and request.POST.get('email') and request.POST.get('password'):
               
                add = Register()
                add.first_name= request.POST['firstname']
                add.last_name= request.POST['lastname']
                add.email= request.POST['email']
                add.save()
                
                d = Handlelogin()
                d.username= request.POST['username']
                d.password= request.POST['password']
                d.register = add
                d.save()
                
                return redirect('/')  

        else:
                return render(request,'register.html')

def users(request):

        reg = Register.objects.all()

        return render(request, 'users.html', {'reg':reg})

def login_handle(request):
        if request.POST:
                username = request.POST['user']
                password = request.POST['pass']

                user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
                
                if user is not None:
                        login(request, user)
                        return HttpResponse("Login Succesfully")
                else:
                        return HttpResponse("Invalid login")
                        
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

I'M using *HTML form* instead of *Django form*, and I have add custom user model **AUTH_USER_MODEL = "register_app.Handlelogin"**  in setting.py  file

Comment: `.password = ...` will not *hash* the password. This is in fact the entire idea of creating a `create_user` function. That being said, please use a `Form`.

Comment: Why not to use builtin Django user/auth capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
d = Handlelogin.objects.create_user(
       username=request.POST['username'],
       password=request.POST['password']
)
d.register = add
d.save()
```